# Inserting unique pointers in deep std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr, unordered-map

How do I insert unique pointers in this deep unordered map that I have?

```
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>>>>
```

(C++14)

Comment: What have you tried? How would you insert a `unique_ptr` into a normal map? It's exactly like that, but through multiple container interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a map

```
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>>>> m;
```

and a`unique_ptr`

```
auto s = std::make_unique<MyStruct>();
```

you can insert the it in the map like this:

```
m[1][2][3] = std::move(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the method i came up with:

```
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>>>> myMap;
auto ptr = std::make_unique<MyStruct>();

// Insert at 17, 18, 19:
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>> tmpLevel3Map;
tmpLevel3Map.emplace(19, std::move(ptr));
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unordered_map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>>> tmpLevel2Map;
tmpLevel2Map.emplace(18, std::move(tmpLevel3Map));
myMap.emplace(17, std::move(tmpLevel2Map));
```